# Automorphisms of del Pezzo surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let S - del Pezzo surface of degree 1 (of degree 2), $k = \mathbb{C}$. I don't know how to proof that groups of automorphisms Aut(S) is finite group.

Comment: You didn't actually write a question, but I assume the question is "how do I prove it"? You should look in Chapter 8 of Dolgachev, _Classical Algebraic Geometry_ (available online). Here is the idea for degree 2: sections of $-K_X$ define a 2:1 cover of $\mathbf P^2$ branched over a smooth quartic curve. Up to finite index, an automorphism of $X$ induces an automorphism of this quartic, so you are done. The story for degree 1 is similar, with a quadric cone now playing the role of the base surface.

Comment: I like this argument from Manin's *Cubic Forms*, Ch. IV. A del Pezzo surface of degree 1 (resp. 2) is isomorphic to the blowup of $\mathbf{P}^2$ at 8 (resp. 7) general points (by MMP for surfaces). Any isomorphism of this blowup must be a bijection on the set of $(-1)$-curves, which are finite (240 resp. 56); you can count these by knowing how curves change under blowing up, adjunction, and Cauchy-Schwarz. The number of automorphisms is therefore finite, and in fact(!) isomorphic to the Weyl group of $E_8$ (resp. $E_7$). I can be more explicit with this if you'd like; just let me know.